# Unable to save entity object to Postgres Database using NEstjs+TypeORM

Tags: typescript, postgresql, webhooks, typeorm, nest

I have an Webhook API that once received webhook event should store the data to database in Nestjs.
KYCStatus is Entity that i created.
Error I received "

kyc-status.entity.ts

```
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  PrimaryColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsAlphanumeric } from 'class-validator';
import { APPLICANT_STATUSES } from 'apps/customer/src/constants';

@Entity({ name: 'KYCStatus' })
export class KYCStatus {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  applicantId: string;

  @Column()
  inspectionId: string;

  @Column()
  correlationId: string;

  @Column()  levelName: string;

  @Column()  externalUserId: string;

  @Column()  type: string;

  @Column()  sandboxMode: string;

  @Column()  reviewResult: object;

  @Column()  reviewStatus: string;

  @Column()  createdAtMs: string;

  @Column()  clientId: string;
}
```

typeorm-configuration

```
const typeOrmConfig: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  username: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  database: 'db',
  entities: BasicEntitiesArray,
  migrationsTableName: 'migrations_history',
  logging: true,
};

export default new DataSource(typeOrmConfig);
```

kyc.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { KYCService } from './kyc.service';
import { KYCController } from './kyc.controller';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { PassportLibModule } from '@app/passport-lib';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { KYCStatus } from '@app/common-lib/entities';

@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule, PassportLibModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
    KYCStatus
  ])],
  controllers: [KYCController],
  providers: [KYCService],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule]
})
export class KYCModule {}
```

kyc.controller.ts

```
@ApiTags('KYC')
@Controller('kyc')
export class KYCController {
  constructor(private readonly kycService: KYCService) {}

  @ApiResponse({ status: HttpStatus.OK })
  @Post('/webhook')
  webhook(@Body() applicantReviewedDto: ApplicantCreatedDTO){
    const webhookStatus = this.kycService.handleEvent(applicantReviewedDto)
  }
}
```

kyc.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class KYCService {
  baseURL = SUMSUB_ROOT_URL;
  config : any = { baseURL : SUMSUB_ROOT_URL};
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(KYCStatus) 
    private readonly applicantRepository: Repository<KYCStatus>) {} 

public handleEvent(appicantReviededDTO: ApplicantCreatedDTO) {
    this.handleApplicantStatus(appicantReviededDTO);   }

  private async handleApplicantStatus(appicantReviededDTO: ApplicantCreatedDTO) {
    try {
      console.log(appicantReviededDTO);
      switch(appicantReviededDTO.type){
        case APPLICANT_STATUSES.APPLICANT_CREATED : {
          // send response to DB to update KYC_VERIFICATION_PENDING
          console.log(this.applicantRepository)
          console.log(await this.applicantRepository.find())
          //await this.applicantRepository.save(appicantReviededDTO)
          break;
        }
        case APPLICANT_STATUSES.APPLICANT_REVIEWED : {
          // send response to DB to update KYC_VERIFICATION_PENDING
          await this.applicantRepository.save(appicantReviededDTO)
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      throw err;
    }   }
```

Once webhook is received, I get following error
What could be possible issue?

> { lynx-cx-customer-1     |   applicantId: '63e512ed34a53356923c5c73',
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |   inspectionId: '63e512ed34a53356923c5c74',
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |   applicantType: 'individual',
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |   correlationId:
> 'd0d024e620ff747a4d38399f4e89566d', lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> levelName: 'basic-kyc-level', lynx-cx-customer-1     |   sandboxMode:
> true, lynx-cx-customer-1     |   externalUserId:
> 'random-postman-user-y5t0zjp5w', lynx-cx-customer-1     |   type:
> 'applicantCreated', lynx-cx-customer-1     |   reviewStatus: 'init',
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |   createdAt: '2023-02-14 14:07:31+0000',
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |   createdAtMs: '2023-02-14 14:07:31.284',
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |   clientId: 'lynxcx.com_29165'
> lynx-cx-customer-1     | } lynx-cx-customer-1     | <ref *1>
> Repository { lynx-cx-customer-1     |   target: [class KYCStatus],
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |   manager: <ref *2> EntityManager {
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |     '@instanceof': Symbol(EntityManager),
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |     repositories: [ lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> [Repository], [Repository], lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> [Repository], [Repository], lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> [Repository], [Repository], lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> [Repository], [Repository], lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> [Repository], [Repository], lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> [Repository], [Repository], lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> [Repository], [Circular *1] lynx-cx-customer-1     |     ],
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |     treeRepositories: [], lynx-cx-customer-1
> |     plainObjectToEntityTransformer:
> PlainObjectToNewEntityTransformer {}, lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> connection: DataSource { lynx-cx-customer-1     |       '@instanceof':
> Symbol(DataSource), lynx-cx-customer-1     |       migrations: [],
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |       subscribers: [], lynx-cx-customer-1
> |       entityMetadatas: [Array], lynx-cx-customer-1     |       name:
> 'default', lynx-cx-customer-1     |       options: [Object],
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |       logger: [AdvancedConsoleLogger],
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |       driver: [MysqlDriver],
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |       manager: [Circular *2],
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |       namingStrategy:
> [DefaultNamingStrategy], lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> metadataTableName: 'typeorm_metadata', lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> queryResultCache: undefined, lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> relationLoader: [RelationLoader], lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> relationIdLoader: [RelationIdLoader], lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> isInitialized: true lynx-cx-customer-1     |     } lynx-cx-customer-1
> |   }, lynx-cx-customer-1     |   queryRunner: undefined
> lynx-cx-customer-1     | } lynx-cx-customer-1     | No metadata for
> "KYCStatus" was found. lynx-cx-customer-1     |  lynx-cx-customer-1
> | /service/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:422 lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> if (!metadata) throw new EntityMetadataNotFoundError(target)
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |                              ^
> lynx-cx-customer-1     | EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for
> "KYCStatus" was found. lynx-cx-customer-1     |     at
> DataSource.getMetadata (/service/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:422:30)
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |     at Repository.get metadata [as metadata]
> (/service/src/repository/Repository.ts:52:40) lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> at Repository.find (/service/src/repository/Repository.ts:476:39)
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |     at KYCService.handleApplicantStatus
> (/service/apps/customer/src/kyc/kyc.service.ts:104:54)
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |     at KYCService.handleEvent
> (/service/apps/customer/src/kyc/kyc.service.ts:94:10)
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |     at KYCController.webhook
> (/service/apps/customer/src/kyc/kyc.controller.ts:42:43)
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |     at
> /service/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:38:29
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |     at processTicksAndRejections
> (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) lynx-cx-customer-1     |
> at
> /service/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
> lynx-cx-customer-1     |     at
> /service/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17
> lynx-cx-nginx-1        | 172.28.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2023:14:07:31 +0000]
> "POST /api/kyc/webhook HTTP/1.1" 201 5 "-" "PMI Service"

What could be the possible issue?

Comment: please share the part you've configured the *typeorm* and `KYCStatus` class.

Comment: Shouldn't the config object pass to the `TypeOrmModule.forRoot`?